# Using vim-latex-live-preview: how to make the pdf view display where you edited the file

Tags: vim, vim-plugin, tex, live-preview

When I'm editing a `.tex` file in `Vim` with the plugin `vim-latex-live-preview` ([available here](https://github.com/xuhdev/vim-latex-live-preview)), I type `:LLPStartPreview` which opens the file at its beginning. Which command do I have to make such that the pdf viewer automatically change the focus to the place where the latest edits are made (which might be at the page e.g. 50 of the pdf)?